# installing docker-compose using standard procedure gives "permission denied"

Tags: bash, docker-compose, permissions, permission-denied, user-permissions

I have done this many times but this is new.
Just following the docker-compose install from docker.com

```
$ sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   633  100   633    0     0   2082      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2075
100 12.1M  100 12.1M    0     0  5940k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 10.8M
```

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

```
$ docker-compose --version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied
```

What is going wrong here ? It used to work before.

Comment: Try `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Comment: I actually did `sudo chmod o-rx /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` but I was wondering  what has changed. I used to install on many machines and it worked as it should but this time, for some reason, it hasn't.

Comment: After you did `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`, do you still have `Permission denied` ?

Comment: Actually, I knew, how to correct it, but I was wondering why it happened on the first place.. No, I dont have the problem, because I changed it with chmod.